# Azure New VM in Powershell -AvailabitySetname

Tags: azure, powershell

Good morning Team.

Need some guidance on `New-AZVM` ----- --`AvailabilitySetName` .

ALL the normal params work just fine, but to use AZ load Balancer, you need a Scale set or `-Availability` Set for VMs.

Normal Centos VM build works 100% without `-AvailabilitySetName`
When I `Get-AzAvailabilitySet` I can see my pre-staged Set listed. 
When I pass the `Get-AzAvailabilitySetName` as given by `Get-AzAvailabilitySet` I get Parameter cannot be resolved.

Does anybody have a working example, Tech-net only states it must be passed as a string .
I validated my Variable with GM and it is. What am I missing?

Comment: I declare the Set with this $azureAvailSet              = "AS-ELMOFRONT"

Comment: And call it like this >

Comment: New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $azureResourceGroup -Location $azureLocation -VM $VirtualMachine -AvailabilitySetName $azureAvailSet  -Verbose

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Put more details of the issue that you are facing.Include the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer after two days of playing around, for those who might have a similar problem, it appears the `new-azvm -availabiltysetname` does not work. You need to define the `AzSET` with .id where you declare the other VM basics like size with `-availabiltysetID` parameter, like this  > #Define the parameters for the new virtual machine.

```
$VirtualMachine = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $azureVmName -VMSize $azureVmSize -AvailabilitySetId $azureAvailSetID
```

Oh like all the others, it needs to be a string

Comment: availability set id cannot be anything but string. its impossible, so the last part is irrelevant